# Kendo Treeview get value from dataBound

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When data is loaded I want to make sure checkbox become `disable` and `uncheck` when `(active == 'n' && checkbox == 1)`. Any Idea what Im missing here? Seem my code not working.

[FULL DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/emIWubIS)

```js
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataBound: function(e){
    this.expand('.k-item');

    var dataItems = this.dataSource.view();
    console.log(dataItems);
    for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++) {
      if( dataItems.active == "n" && dataItems.checked == 1){
         $(e.node).find(".k-group input").prop('checked', false);
         $(e.node).find(".k-group input").prop('disabled', true);
      }
    }
  },
  template: "<span #if(item.active=='n'){# style='color:red' #} #>#: item.group != null ? item.group : item.ledger #</span>" ,
  dataSource: [
    { ledger: "Title 1st", active:"y", checked: 0 },
      { group: "subTitle1", active:"y",checked: 1 },
      { group: "subTitle2", active:"n",checked: 1 },
      { group: "subTitle3", active:"y",checked: 0 },
      { ledger: "Title 2nd", active:"n", checked: 1}
  ],
  checkboxes: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution

```js
dataBound: function(e){
  this.expand('.k-item');

  var dataItems = this.dataSource.view();
  console.log(dataItems);
  for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++) {
    if (dataItems[i].active == "n" && dataItems[i].checked == 1) { 
        dataItems[i].set("checked", false);
        dataItems[i].set("enabled", false); 
    }
  }
},
```